# Clearing element cache in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, cache-control, cakephp-2.1

I echo one element from my ctp file like this:

```
 echo $this->element('myelement',
                array( "name" => $name) ,
                array( "cache" => "false")
            );
```

Elements is shown successfully.
But it seems like the same element is shown.
It doesn't change after a refresh.

I couldn't clear element cache.
I tried

- Cache::clear();
- clearCache();

but didn't work.

My debug level is default: 2

Should i check any other thing?
Thank you

Comment: FYI, at debug > 0 no caching is done, so clearing the cache is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#passing-variables-into-an-element

thats probably because "false" can be interpreted as TRUE - you need to actually pass a false value:

```
"cache" => false
```

without ".

Comment: costa is right. in debug mode caching will be skipped. it would have helped to know if the file is actually created.

Comment: Thank you. I change it to false without quotes, but still element wasn't refreshed. What should i check more?

Comment: I guess we all are still not sure what exactly your problem ist. is there an actual "cache file" in your /tmp/cache/views folder?

Comment: Yes there is a file in "/tmp/cache/" root directory with the element's name. Shouldn't it be there if debug level is >0.